Strong Induction: Exponents

Can someone please explain this to me? I apologize if the answer is simple but I’m learning first-year proofs, and am getting a hold of it, but in this case of strong induction (and another done in class) there is this easy back and forth switching between exponents that I can’t understand the rule for.
As well, if anyone has any recommended resources that sort of gives an explanation on different cases or why this is in general, I’d very much appreciate it as I can’t properly word what I’m looking for to get information. Thank you.

That just looks wrong.  It's certainly not the case that $(-1)^k - 2(-1)^{k-1} = 3(-1)^{k+1}$... there's a minus sign missing.  The next two lines don't seem equivalent to each other, either... how did the second $6$ become a $2$??

Welcome to SE! You can use mathJax to type out your questions as well. Also please include the original question/problem for context. Hint: Think about what $-(-1)^k$ is.

The general rule applying to the exponents is just that $a^k = a \cdot a^{k-1} = (1/a) \cdot a^{k+1}$.  When $a=-1$, this gets you $(-1)^k = -(-1)^{k-1}=-(-1)^{k+1}$.  When $a=2$, this gets you $2^k=2\cdot 2^{k-1}$.  The derivation in the image you gave seems to be incorrect in several places.  Here's a correct one:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
a_{k+1} &=& 6 \cdot 2^{k-1} + 2 (-1)^{k} + 4(-1)^{k-1} \\
&=&3\cdot\left(2 \cdot 2^{k-1}\right) -2(-1)^{k+1}+4(-1)^{k+1} \\
&=&3\cdot2^k+2(-1)^{k+1}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Thank you very much. I couldn’t find this info anywhere but could see it was happening. I get it now.
